# How do I use a wildcard in an attribute with ldapsearch and Active Directory?

Tags: linux, active-directory, ldap-query

I have users in AD with `memberOf` attributes having either `cn=ad-users103,ou=hr,ou=groups,dc=mycorp,dc=com` or `cn=ad-users203,ou=hr,ou=groups,dc=mycorp,dc=com`. I'd like to use a filter like `cn=ad-users*` but it's not returning results. I'm using `ldapsearch` in Linux to test my filter.

I've tried using a filter like this which returns user info:

`ldapsearch  -D "cn=admin..." -b "dc=mycorp,dc=com" -x -H ldaps://ldap.mycorp.com -w $PASS -E pr=100/noprompt "memberOf=cn=ad-users203,ou=hr,ou=groups,dc=mycorp,dc=com"`

When I add a wildcard (taking example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564120/using-wildcards-in-ldap-search-filters-queries?r=SearchResults)), I don't get any results:

`ldapsearch  -D "cn=admin..." -b "dc=mycorp,dc=com" -x -H ldaps://ldap.mycorp.com -w $PASS -E pr=100/noprompt "memberOf=cn=ad-users*"`

I've tried moving the splat to different positions in the filter to no avail. Should a search work this way or do I need to use something like `(&(memberOf=cn=ad-users103...)(memberOf=cn=ad-users203...))` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memberOF is a distinguishedName attribute value and wildcards are not supported on distinguishedNames as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28984362/88122

And I think your AND search of

```
(&(memberOf=cn=ad-users103...)(memberOf=cn=ad-users203...))
```

Should be and OR search:

```
(|(memberOf=cn=ad-users103...)(memberOf=cn=ad-users203...))
```

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying. I had no idea wildcards were handled differently depending on attribute. You are also correct about the OR filter.